# System of linear equation of 3 variables and 4 equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I need to express $(3,4,-2,-1)$ as a linear combination of $\frac{1}{2}(1,1,1,1) , \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(-1,-1,0,2)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{50}}(-1,-3,6,-2)$

I create a system of linear equation:$$(3,4,-2,-1)=a\frac{1}{2}(1,1,1,1)+b\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(-1,-1,0,2)+c\frac{1}{\sqrt{50}}(-1,-3,6,-2)$$

The answer in my textbook is $a=2,b=-\frac{9}{\sqrt{6}},c=\frac{25}{\sqrt{50}}$

In any way I try to solve this system of equations, I fail to get these answers. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should show us your calculations.

Comment: you just use online calculator : Wolframe Alfa is  good I guess. or you can just google online solve system of linear equations.

Comment: Just set $A=a/2,\ B=b/\sqrt{6},\ C=c/\sqrt{50}$ and solve the integer system.

Comment: @zwim how exactly?

Comment: Maybe start by writing the system obtained in your question... $A-B-C=3$ etc.

Comment: Well, you’re clearly doing something wrong, but if you don’t show us your work, it’s impossible to say what. I will note that there’s an easier way to do this: notice that the three given vectors form an orthonormal set and take advantage of that to compute coordinates directly.